# Rowmapper is best?

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I used resultset class to get database information from mysql in jsp. Now i working Spring MVC. So what will i use? Resultset or Rowmapper?

**RowMapper**

```
public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int line) throws SQLException {
        UserExtractor userExtractor = new UserExtractor();
        return userExtractor.extractData(resultSet);
    }

}

public class UserExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<User> {

    public User extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

        User user = new User();

        user.setUserId(resultSet.getInt(1));
        user.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(2));
        user.setLastName(resultSet.getString(3));
        user.setGender(resultSet.getString(4));
        user.setCity(resultSet.getString(5));

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RowMapper` is less raw therefore preferred. `ResultSetExtractor` is for use cases which cannot be served by `RowMapper`.

Comment: It makes sense for me. In MVC pattern you can also create some webModel layer where you can put rendered data. So your data can be combined and include more objects and in your jsp you can get that webModel and display values from it.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to MVC in any way, so retagged as spring-jdbc.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference between `RowMapper` and `ResultSetExtractor` is something your question seems to ignore:

- `RowMapper` produces one object *per row*;
- `ResultSetExtractor` produces one object per entire `ResultSet`.

Therefore the return type of  `ResultSetExtractor` cannot be `User`, assuming one result row represents one user.

Generally, prefer `RowMapper` when it can support your use case. If your end result will be a list of `User` objects, then there is no need to manually do the iteration over the `ResultSet`, adding to a list you must create, which is what you'll need to do with `ResultSetExtractor`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your situation `RowMapper` is a better solution, considering that there are many more solutions like Object Relational Mapping(ORM), JDO, etc. But Out of the two given to choose, RowMapper will extract the data on per-row basis, into individual result objects, so less headache of iteration for the output desired

**ResultSet**

A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries the database.

A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

**RowMapper**

An interface used by JdbcTemplate for mapping rows of a ResultSet on a per-row basis. Implementations of this interface perform the actual work of mapping each row to a result object, but don't need to worry about exception handling. SQLExceptions will be caught and handled by the calling JdbcTemplate.

[Ref Link 1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html)

[Ref Link 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: I rolled back your edit to the question, since it changed the original question too much - OP is not using rowmapper properly which is quite clear based on the original code posted.